# How to build for all platform using vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-cli, electron-builder

Is possible to make multiple platform build using [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html)? Anyone have experience with it? What will be the correct plugin configuration if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a little too broad. Anyway, I did try using this, so far so good, but still in progress. I also tested Windows only, not sure if this works on Ubuntu, for example.

Comment: From vue ui it's seems that is possible to configure the platform for the build process. I'm testing the macOS build generated by the process and works as expected, I need to try windows version and linux using VirtualBox

Comment: Well, it definitely works on Windows. Other than that, I can't tell much yet.

Comment: Tested after some hours spent on updating VirtualBox. Seems to work fine in windows10-64bit Home ver. N